# Use static or dynamic private IP address on Azure?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

What is the good practice on Azure, always set a Static IP address on network interface or use the dynamic (DHCP) option?

I prefer to use the dynamic IP because it's easier to scale UP and down the virtual machines. But I have a sysadmin coworker and he say me that not a good practice to use the dynamic option.

These virtual machines are behind a load balancer, nobody is using it directly.

Comment: dynamic seems better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dynamic IP in this scenario sounds better choice, you can use static IP in below mentioned scenarios,
•   When you must update firewall rules to communicate with your Azure resources.
•   DNS name resolution, where a change in IP address would require updating A records.
•   Your Azure resources communicate with other apps or services that use an IP address-based security model.
•   You use SSL certificates linked to an IP address.